# I don't know Maschke's theorem in the group representation.

Tags: representation-theory

I have a question about the Maschke's theorem in the group representation.

I know that Maschke's theorem says that "Every representation of a finite group having positive degree is completely reducible, i.e. it has a direct sum of irreducible G-modules.".

I'm very confused when a G-module is different to the given G-module.

More precisely, if G is a finite group and V is a G-module with $\dim V>0$, then V is a direct sum of irreducible G-submodules $V_i$. Now, if W is another G-module, then by the Maschke's theorem, W also has a decomposition of irreducible G-submodules. I wonder if the irreducible G-submodules of W are precisely $V_i$. That is, I think the irreducible factors does not depend on G-module, and depend only on the given group G.

Is it right? I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: No, this is clearly not true, as can be checked by a few small examples. What is true is that the possible $V_i$ are determined by $G$ (up to isomorphism of $G$-modules), as these are just the irreducible $G$-modules.

Comment: Then, if V is isomorphic to W as G-modules, then is it right?

Comment: Yes, clearly if the modules are isomorphic then they have the same summands.

Comment: Is the reason Maschke's theorem??

Comment: I am not sure what you are really asking here. Maschke's theorem says that the modules are completely reducible. That the indecomposable summands of isomorphic modules are the same is not related to that theorem.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Ummm.... I give you the main question as an example. If $V=V_1+2V_2+V_3$, then $W$ cannot have an irreducible factor $V_4$, that is, $W=V_1+V_2+V_4$ cannot be G-module. But, if $W=V_1+V_2$, then this case is possible to occur by the Maschke's theorem, I think.

Comment: What is the relation between $V$ and $W$ in that question?

Comment: just $V$ and $W$ are $G$-modules. ( of course, $G$ is finite )

Comment: Are you sure? Because if $V_4$ is a $G$-module then clearly so is $V_1 + V_2 + V_4$.

Comment: Yeah, but $V_i$ are not isomorphic. Even if $V$ has such a decomposition, is it possible to have the decomposition $W=V_1+V_2+V_4$?

Comment: Yes, just take the direct sum of those modules.

Comment: Ah, then you mean the decompositon depends on both $G$-module and the group $G$, right?

Comment: Yes, the decomposition is something the module has, so clearly it depends on which module you take.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I understand it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what field you are working over, but I imagine it's probably something safe like $\Bbb C$. Really you ought to say that the irreducible factors depend on both $G$ and the field $F$.

Obviously the irreducible submodules of two given modules may be totally unrelated. Just consider two nonisomorphic simple modules.

What *is* true is that all the simple modules will appear in the regular representation $F[G]$.

Comment: Yeah, I mean $F=\mathbb{C}$. I want to know that "all the simple modules will appear in the regular representation $F[G]$". Are the simple modules G-submodules of $F[G]$?

Comment: @JeongHobin I haven't really thought about $G$-submodules, but my understanding is that they are equivalent to $F[G]$ submodules of $F[G]$, if you extend the $G$ action linearly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment :(

Comment: An action $G\times V\to V$ should correspond with a module action $F[G]\times V\to V$